# Is there any GTKmm version compilation flag?

Tags: c++, compilation, conditional-statements, gtkmm

I have a C++ application using GTKmm version 3.

From one version of the library to another, some method definition change so I would like to handle them in order to allow my sources to compile with a previous and actual version of GTKmm.

When I have written a kernel module, I did the same thing using conditional operators like the following:

```
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(3,6,0)
  // Something is done when kernel version is 3.6 or higher
#else
  // Something else is done for older versions
#endif
```

So the question is: is this possible in C++ and GTKMM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - gtkmm has the defines `GTKMM_MAJOR_VERSION`, `GTKMM_MINOR_VERSION`, and `GTKMM_MICRO_VERSION`.